# Is 'the power of mathematics' cliched?

Tags: word-choice

I wish to write something like

> I am astonished by the power of maths in solving complex problems in physics, chemistry and economics

Is it a bit of cliched to say 'the power of maths'? Will it be better to use the word 'ability' or are there better alternatives that would make the sentence more sincere and reflecting the author's true feeling?

Comment: *Usefulness* is elegant for its simplicity.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that "maths" sounds perfectly fine in the UK but very strange in the US.

Comment: Can you give us some more context?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Chad. I've added more details and context, hopefully this makes my question more clear.

Comment: The idea that there is something deeply significant about the fact that maths "works so well" for understanding and controlling our environment isn't exactly new, but it's [more of a hot topic today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(the+power+of+math)+%2B+(the+power+of+maths)+%2B+(the+power+of+mathematics)&year_start=1820&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28the%20power%20of%20math%29%20%2B%20%28the%20power%20of%20maths%29%20%2B%20%28the%20power%20of%20mathematics%29%3B%2Cc0) than it ever was before. It's certainly not a "cliche".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think "power" is cliched here -- it sounds like exactly the right word in this sentence.

And as mentioned in the comment, "maths" may be correct in the UK, but sounds odd to my native US English ears. I would use "math" or "mathematics" instead.